# Who got some sun on the voyage?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

We meek internationalists go on a little afternoon voyage

*Who got some sun on the voyage?*

Hint #1:

> My question history (previous puzzles) may prove useful.

Hint #2:

> interNATionalists

Hint #3:

> You might get some help from a girl with a *Goodly Heart*

Hint #4:

> You also might get help from a *hot lady ogre*

Comment: Interestingly, the anagram *Toto, I've got a feeling we're not in Kansas anymore* is contained within this

Comment: That is interesting - what else is contained in it?  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Elliot

First clue, thanks to Smock

> As Smock pointed out in the comments - "the anagram *Toto, I've got a feeling we're not in Kansas anymore* is contained within" the puzzle. The rest of the letters in the puzzle can be rearranged to spell "Elliot tan".

Hint 2

> NAT is an anagram of tan

Hints 3 and 4

> Both anagrams of Dorothy Gale - the main character from *The Wizard of Oz*

Comment: That is the answer!  Good job.

Comment: Lol, i thought that was just an amusing (to me) coincidence

Answer (score 6):

It was ...

> a bunch of Amazon fulfillment center workers on a day cruise.

That seems unlikely.

> Well, yes. But possible.
>  Toward the end of 2018, Amazon started [hiring over 1,000 workers](https://www.miamitimesonline.com/business/amazon-to-hire-more-than-workers-for-opa-locka-warehouse/article_79aabd70-b13a-11e8-a41e-8f1bfa778f19.html) for its new warehouse and fulfillment center in the newly opened [Carrie Meek International Business Park](https://www.foundrycommercial.com/story-room/news/2010840-foundry-breaks-ground-on-carrie-meek-international-business-park-and-amazon-fulfillment-center-in-miami.stml) in Opa-Locka, Florida—located mere minutes<sup>1</sup> from Miami Beach, from which a number of businesses run chartered day cruises.
>
>  The folks working at the "Amazon Mega Warehouse" — which, by the way, you can take a [tour of (look for "Opa Locka, FL (MIA1)" on the list)](https://www.aboutamazon.com/amazon-fulfillment-center-tours/where-you-can-tour-an-amazon-fulfillment-center-in-north-america) — are, of course, also working in the Carrie Meek International Business Park, making them *Meek International*ists. Put them on a day cruise, *et voilà*.
>
>
>  <sup>1</sup> ok, maybe [40 to 50 minutes](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Amazon+Mega+Warehouse,+14000+NW+37th+Ave,+Opa-locka,+FL+33054/Biscayne+Lady+Yacht+Charters,+401+Biscayne+Boulevard+Pier+1,+Miami,+FL+33132/@25.8496399,-80.2928182,40231m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x88d9b01e71d39a97:0x3627ad6edc747fd!2m2!1d-80.2608588!2d25.9007199!1m5!1m1!1s0x88d9b4277eba784d:0x6eb2b2f86c51a44d!2m2!1d-80.185422!2d25.777244!3e0).  Still, reasonable.

Comment: This is not the answer, though I like the approach.  This puzzle is more word-play and less research based.  Interesting find, though!

Answer (score 5):

My version (well, it's quite unrealistic):

> Kim Jong-un

Explanation:

> "Meek internationalists" may be a delegation from DPR Korea (North Korea) visiting Republic of Korea (South Korea) (the voyage can be *little* due to the small distance between the bordering countries). The leader of the North Korean delegation (Kim Jong-un of course) gets a Samsung (pronounced much like *some sun*) cellphone as a gift from the South Korean side.

Comment: Not correct, but good attempt.  Much more word-play at play here.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer:**

Based on hints 3 and 4:

> There's something anagram related going on. That also ties in with hint #1, as previous @MetaZen puzzles involved anagrams.

From hint 2:

> InterNATionalists seems to be pointing out that they got a TAN, as per the question.

So to find out who got some sun, presumably:

> We find a suitable anagram that fits the rest of it, possibly with some wordplay involved first .... which I haven't quite managed yet

Comment: This is the right way forward.  Pretty big spoiler in the comments above!  Still a little bit of work to get the final answer.